# Tips of making a list in email

Tags: html-email, padding, outlook-2010, outlook-2013

I am designing an email template. I have a running list of brand names hyperlinked to their websites. I would like it to be displayed inline for full-width, and stacked for narrow screens. I had separators in the past like a bullet or a vertical rule such as this: "|". But in mobile it's awkward considering only one name appears per line.

The next thing I tried was to enclose each list item in a border, but Outlook10/13 aren't handling the padding and margin as you know. I want a simple solution that I can show to novices when they populate the template. Any ideas? I'm adding screenshots of what I tried with the borders. But any other idea is welcome.

Thanks!!!

Full Width:

[image: Full-width]

Mobile:

[image: Mobile]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of ways myself and one thing i found out was having logos in place of links often work better. I know images have to be downloaded but once they are downloaded it looks good. If you do go with images, you can style the alt tags to look like above when its not loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, it is required to use text in my case, and no workarounds. As I said, marketers may need to go in and just type the new info each time.

Comment: Creating a template? Then yes stick to text, with out pipes will be a better idea.

Comment: Thanks, we decided to simply underline each one, no commas, no pipes, just regular links one after the other with one space.

Comment: Perfect. That's the best way for hybrid templates as well.